# Could not find the correct Provider<Database>

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter development.
I am creating small application by checking few examples I found.
The application uses firebase authentication and database.

My main.dart file does not have anything. It simply load a landing page

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AuthBase>(
      create: (context) => Auth(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Hello',
        home: LandingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the landing page, I check whether use has login or not
In both cases they go to HomePage()
But if there is a user database get initialized with user id.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          User user = snapshot.data;

          if (user == null) {
            print("no login");

            return Provider<Database>(
              create: (context) => FirestoreDatabase(uid: null),
              child: HomePage(),
            );
          } else {
            print("has a login");
            print(user.uid);

            return Provider<User>.value(
              value: user,
              child: Provider<Database>(
                  create: (context) => FirestoreDatabase(uid: user.uid),
                  child: HomePage()),
            );
          }
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The home page get loaded correctly.
In the Home page I load another page to view users posts (If user is logged in).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('My Posts'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPosts()));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In my posts I tried to access database following manner

```
final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);
```

When i go to posts page i get following error

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Database> above this MyPosts Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
```

I assume the way I am using providers is the reason for this error.
Can someone please provide some help to fix this error?

Is this the correct way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

add a `Multiprovider` above your `MaterialApp` and create your `Database` provider in it.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => AuthBase()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => Database()), // add your Database provider here
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Hello',
        home: LandingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not seems to work. The AuthBase class does not have ChangeNotifier, same goes for Database class.

Comment: Can anyone provide some help on this?